# IntelliJ - Select source code location while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to step into a JDK source, but the versions of the local JDK and the remote JDK are different, hence the line numbers do not match. I have downloaded the sources of the remote JDK, but I can't find out how to tell IntelliJ to use them.

How can I tell IntelliJ to use a specific JDK sources for debugging?

Comment: Can you not just download the remote, add it to your local, and use it?

Comment: I'm debugging a cloud application that broke after JVM update. I have already downloaded the JVM and it;s source, but I cannot find out how to tell intellij to use it. My Idea is using the bundled JVM 8 that come as part of teh idea download, while my application uses Java 7. Also I don;t want to run Idea with the other JDK, as it does not support any GUI stuff.

Comment: Set the project JDK: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: @Mark Thanks Mark, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Added as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your *JDK* based on this:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

```
To configure a project SDK

    Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
    In the left-hand pane, under Project Settings, click Project.
    On the page that opens in the right-hand part of the dialog, select the necessary SDK from the Project SDK list.
    If the desired SDK is not present in the list, click New and select the necessary SDK type.
    In the dialog that opens, select the SDK home directory and click OK.

    As a result, a new SDK is added to IntelliJ IDEA and selected as the project SDK.
    To view or edit the SDK name and contents, click Edit. (The SDK page will open.)
    Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.

To configure a module SDK

    Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
    In the left-hand pane, under Project Settings, click Modules.
    In the area under project_structure_toolbar_2_modules, select the module of interest.
    In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Module page, select the Dependencies tab.
    Select the SDK from the Module SDK list. (To select the project SDK, select Project SDK. Note that if you change the project SDK later, the module SDK will change accordingly.)
    If the desired SDK is not present in the list, click New and select the necessary SDK type.
    In the dialog that opens, select the SDK home directory and click OK.

    As a result, a new SDK is added to IntelliJ IDEA and associated with the module.
    To view or edit the SDK name and contents, click Edit. (The SDK page will open.)
    Click OK in the Project Structure dialog.
```